# Oracle how to optimise a Count Case when query to return a matrix table

Tags: sql, oracle, matrix, count, case

I have a table showing on people's birthdays they are in a category (Birthday wave 1 Column: VIP, LOYAL, REGULAR, ONE-OFFS, LAPSED, INACTIVE, GONE AWAY, NO RFM) and where they move to by their next birthday called 'Birthday Wave 2'.

I have created case statements to count category movement however it is quite long.

```
select DISTINCT Birthday_Wave_1
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'VIP' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LOYAL' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS a
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'VIP' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'REGULAR' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS b
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'VIP' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'ONE-OFFS' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS c
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'VIP' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NEW' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS d
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'VIP' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LAPSED' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS e
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'VIP' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'INACTIVE' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS f
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'VIP' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'GONE AWAY' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS g
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'VIP' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NO RFM' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS h

,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LOYAL' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'VIP' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS i
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LOYAL' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'REGULAR' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS j
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LOYAL' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'ONE-OFFS' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS k
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LOYAL' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NEW' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS l
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LOYAL' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LAPSED' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS m
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LOYAL' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'INACTIVE' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS n
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LOYAL' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'GONE AWAY' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS o
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LOYAL' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NO RFM' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS p

,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'REGULAR' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'VIP' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) as q
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'REGULAR' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LOYAL' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS r
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'REGULAR' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'ONE-OFFS' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS s
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'REGULAR' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NEW' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS t
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'REGULAR' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LAPSED' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS u
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'REGULAR' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'INACTIVE' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS v
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'REGULAR' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'GONE AWAY' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS w
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'REGULAR' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NO RFM' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS x

,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'ONE-OFFS' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'VIP' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) as y
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'ONE-OFFS' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LOYAL' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS z
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'ONE-OFFS' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'REGULAR' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS aa
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'ONE-OFFS' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NEW' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS ab
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'ONE-OFFS' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LAPSED' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS ac
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'ONE-OFFS' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'INACTIVE' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS ad
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'ONE-OFFS' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'GONE AWAY' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS ae
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'ONE-OFFS' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NO RFM' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS af

,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NEW' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'VIP' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) as ag
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NEW' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LOYAL' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS ah
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NEW' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'REGULAR' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS ai
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NEW' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'ONE-OFFS' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS aj
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NEW' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LAPSED' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS ak
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NEW' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'INACTIVE' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS al
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NEW' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'GONE AWAY' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS am
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NEW' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NO RFM' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS an

,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LAPSED' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'VIP' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) as ao
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LAPSED' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LOYAL' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS apa
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LAPSED' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'REGULAR' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS aq
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LAPSED' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'ONE-OFFS' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS ar
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LAPSED' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NEW' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS art
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LAPSED' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'INACTIVE' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS at
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LAPSED' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'GONE AWAY' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS au
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'LAPSED' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NO RFM' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS av

,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'INACTIVE' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'VIP' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) as aw
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'INACTIVE' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LOYAL' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS ax
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'INACTIVE' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'REGULAR' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS ay
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'INACTIVE' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'ONE-OFFS' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS az
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'INACTIVE' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NEW' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS ba
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'INACTIVE' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LAPSED' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bb
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'INACTIVE' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'GONE AWAY' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bc
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'INACTIVE' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NO RFM' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bd

,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'GONE AWAY' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'VIP' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) as be
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'GONE AWAY' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LOYAL' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS be
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'GONE AWAY' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'REGULAR' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bf
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'GONE AWAY' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'ONE-OFFS' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bg
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'GONE AWAY' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NEW' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bh
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'GONE AWAY' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LAPSED' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bi
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'GONE AWAY' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'INACTIVE' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bj
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'GONE AWAY' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NO RFM' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bk

,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NO RFM' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'VIP' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) as bl
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NO RFM' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LOYAL' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bm
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NO RFM' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'REGULAR' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bn
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NO RFM' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'ONE-OFFS' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bo
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NO RFM' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'NEW' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bp
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NO RFM' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LAPSED' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bq
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NO RFM' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'INACTIVE' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS br
,COUNT(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'NO RFM' and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'GONE AWAY' THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) AS bs

from rfm_bd
GROUP BY Birthday_Wave_1;
```

The following as a crop of the output which I then manually delete the extra data to create the category matrix in excel.
[SQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX3J1.png)

This is the end product. Is there an optimised way to create this matrix in SQL Oracle?
[Excel Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JELTz.png)

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that distinct immediately after select makes no sense. Having the GROUP BY Birthday_Wave_1 certainly assures that you will have no duplicates.

Then, I'd try something along the lines below:

```
With tb_grp1 as (
  select birthday_wave_1, birthday_wave_2, count(*) cnt
  from rfm_bd
  GROUP BY Birthday_Wave_1
)
select Birthday_Wave_1
  ,sum(case when Birthday_Wave_1 = 'VIP' 
     and Birthday_Wave_2 = 'LOYAL' 
      THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) AS a
  --- the other columns
from tb_grp1
GROUP BY Birthday_Wave_1;
```

Not sure how much the above treatment will help, but that distinct certainly is no good.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look into [PIVOT](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html) to get your "matrix":

```sql
-- Sample data
WITH
    tbl (ID, BDAY_1, BDAY_2, CONTACT) AS
        (   Select 1,  'VIP',       'LOYAL',        101 From Dual   Union All
            Select 2,  'LOYAL',     'REGULAR',      102 From Dual   Union All
            Select 3,  'REGULAR',   'VIP',          103 From Dual   Union All
            Select 4,  'ONE-OFFS',  'LAPSED',       104 From Dual   Union All
            Select 5,  'LAPSED',    'INACTIVE',     105 From Dual   Union All
            Select 6,  'INACTIVE',  'ONE-OFFS',     106 From Dual   Union All
            Select 7,  'GONE AWAY', 'NO RFM',       107 From Dual   Union All
            Select 8,  'NO RFM',    'GONE AWAY',    108 From Dual   Union All
            Select 9,  'REGULAR',   'VIP',          109 From Dual   Union All
            Select 10, 'LAPSED',    'LOYAL',        110 From Dual   Union All
            Select 11, 'NO RFM',    'VIP',          111 From Dual   Union All
            Select 12, 'VIP',       'INACTIVE',     112 From Dual   Union All
            Select 13, 'VIP',       'LOYAL',        113 From Dual   Union All
            Select 14, 'VIP',       'GONE AWAY',    114 From Dual
        )
--  SQL
SELECT BDAY_1, Sum(A) "VIP", Sum(B) "LOYAL", Sum(C) "REGULAR", Sum(D) "ONE_OFFS", Sum(E) "LAPSED", Sum(F) "INACTIVE", Sum(G) "GONE_AWAY", Sum(H) "NO_RFM"
FROM (   Select ID, BDAY_1, BDAY_2, CONTACT From tbl )
    PIVOT   (Count(ID) For BDAY_2 IN('VIP' "A", 'LOYAL' "B", 'REGULAR' "C", 'ONE-OFFS' "D", 'LAPSED' "E", 'INACTIVE' "F", 'GONE AWAY' "G", 'NO RFM' "H")
            )
GROUP BY BDAY_1

BDAY_1           VIP      LOYAL    REGULAR   ONE_OFFS     LAPSED   INACTIVE  GONE_AWAY     NO_RFM
--------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
NO RFM             1          0          0          0          0          0          1          0 
VIP                0          2          0          0          0          1          1          0 
GONE AWAY          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          1 
ONE-OFFS           0          0          0          0          1          0          0          0 
LAPSED             0          1          0          0          0          1          0          0 
INACTIVE           0          0          0          1          0          0          0          0 
LOYAL              0          0          1          0          0          0          0          0 
REGULAR            2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
```

Note: this is just an option based on sample data - you should adjust it to your data tables/columns and db context.